# .NET framework version conflict issue

Tags: c#, .net

When I load my application, I receive the following error:
[image]

I immediately went and tried to install the version but it notified me that it's already installed:
[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Who ever down voted this I would like to ask why?

Comment: Try the .net Framework repair tool: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=246062

Comment: What is in your app.config file? Do you have a `supportedRuntime` element?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,ServerVersion=v4.6.1" />`

Comment: Hmm that doesn't look right try this instead: `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />`

Comment: This worked thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You `app.config` fie contains an invalid value for the SKU id in your [`supportedRuntime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element) element. For some reason it is this:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,ServerVersion=v4.6.1" />
```

But it should look more like this:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
```

You can see the valid list of values in [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element#sku).